# PHP/MySQL: Path Error: [function.require]: failed to open stream:

Tags: php, mysql, database, google-maps

I have applied the google map to my local server via Xampp. I have moved it to my web hosting server and I can not get it to connect to the databse. I was able to get other db connections to work but the issue here is I must be puting the file path in incorrectly. I am using the same file structure as on my local machine.

The Errors:

```
Warning: require(../includes/core/db/map_dbinfo.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/includes/state_map/phpsqlajax_genxml2.php on line 2

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../includes/core/db/map_dbinfo.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/includes/state_map/phpsqlajax_genxml2.php on line 2
```

Anyone know why it's throwing these errors now but not on local machine and how I can go about fixing it?

I really have no idea where to start or even how to word this question. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are standing in `.../includes/states_map/phpsqlajax_genxml2.php` and trying to reach "`../includes/core/db/map_dbinfo.php`". If you go back one directory from `states_map` you get to includes, and then you try to find includes under the includes directory.

Change the include to `../../includes/core/db/map_dbinfo.php`

Why this is happening? Probably because you on your local server has `.../includes` added in you r `include_path` in php, which then will try `includes/../includes/...`

Comment: \0/ Thanks Worked great! Will accepet in 4 mins.